# stylelint breaks for font namespace?

Tags: sass, stylelint

I have a file called `foo.scss` with contents:

```
.foo {
    font: {
        family: arial;
        weight: 600;
    }
}
```

Linting with stylelint 8.4.0 on the command line results in this output:

`foo.scss
 2:5  ✖  Cannot parse selector   parseError`

However, I expected this sass syntax to work since it's described in the sass documentation at https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to stylelint 9.4 (from 8.4) fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `:` after `font` so sass is treating `font` as a selector, and `family` and `weight` as properties. You need to add the `:` after `font` to achieve the desired result:

```
.foo {
    font: {
        family: arial;
        weight: 600;
    }
}
```

Seems that `stylelint` can't handle some of the special `scss` syntax. I think the best option will be to lint the `css` output (thru [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss)) instead of the `scss` itself.

Please refer to [Parsing non-standard syntax](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/css-processors/#parsing-non-standard-syntax) to properly lint `scss` or `sass` files.

Comment: Thanks for the response - you are correct. I reproduced the original problem incorrectly and missed the fact that the error changed. I will update my question to show this. The error after adding the missing colon is ` 2:5  ✖  Cannot parse selector   parseError`

Comment: @AlexMA and what's in `2:5`? What is your css output? Can you post it?

Comment: 2:5 is the `font: {` bit. css output is `.foo {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600; }
`

Comment: @AlexMA but StyleLint is a linter for CSS and not SASS; why are you applying the linter to a SASS (or scss) file?

Comment: According to the docs stylelint is supposed to do sass. I have been using it for months for sass work. https://stylelint.io/user-guide/faq/#how-do-i-lint-scss-less-or-other-non-standard-syntax

Comment: @AlexMA and you are using `postcss` to lint your css output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171490/discussion-between-alexma-and-muecas).